# How to assign a array to a pointer in a struct?

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following structs as example:

```
#define MAX_PEOPLE 16
typedef struct {
  int age;
}Person;

typedef struct {
  Person *people;
  int numPeople;
}Team;
```

I'm trying to allocate an array of persons in a function, passed by parameters. My `Team` is supposed to store an array of 16 pointers of `Person`. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
void initiateTeam(Team * team){
  team->numPeople = MAX_PEOPLE;
  Person *p[MAX_PEOPLE];
  for(int i=0; i<MAX_PEOPLE;i++){
    p[i] = malloc(sizeof(Person);
  }
  team->people = &p[0];
}
```

I printed out the addresses of my `team->people[i]` and I'm getting random junk. Why is the assingment `team->people = &p[0]` wrong? Shouldn't it get the first address of my array then perform pointer arithmetic?

Comment: for one thing you need to change your malloc to be sizeOf(Person)

Comment: How are you using that array? You allocated space for pointers, not structures

Comment: Oh yeah! I see why, for the array, we need the size of there persons not the size the pointer

Comment: @MarcoA. I will be adding/deleteing `People` from my `Team`,

Comment: The array is allocated on the stack... you are in deep poo poo

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it.. do you want an array of pointers or objects?

Comment: @MarcoA. At first I thought storing objects was right, but then someone said I'll be initializing them in the stack and it loses scope after my function reaches the end. So I think now, the approach should be allocating a large piece of memory to fit my `people` array, then add `Person`s to it after I've initialized the space.

Comment: @lzc Okay, I edited my answer accordingly. You should have made that clear anyway

Comment: Your code is still allocating an array on the stack.  However, the value set into team is a pointer to the first malloc'd area.  Suggest a ptr on the stack, then malloc an array of pointers, then malloc for each entry in that array of pointers, then team->people = contents of ptr on stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in the comments you stated that you're trying to allocate an array of `Person` objects and **not pointers**, you should rather do:

```
void addPeople(Team * team){
    team->numPeople = MAX_PEOPLE;
    team->people = malloc(sizeof(Person) * MAX_PEOPLE);
}
```

mind that there's no `*` in `sizeof` since you don't want an array of pointers but of objects. You will later be able to access the single elements (i.e. each `Person` object) with

```
team->people[2].age = 25; // The third person in the array
```

Finally, remember to free your memory.

Answer (score 2):

You are pointing `team->people` to a statically defined array of person pointers. Once the function ends, the stack pointer moves back to where main left off, erasing all previously local memory in the addPeople function. You need to malloc `p`, and return it from the function

Comment: the array (`p`) is on the stack, not 'statically'.

Comment: @Javier I mean static as in Constant size, not the key word static.

Comment: the phrase "a statically defined array" has a definite meaning, and it's not for arrays in the stack, constant size or not.

Answer (score 1):

your variable `p` is allocated in the stack of the `addPeople()` function.  The assignment `team->people = &p[0]` (which is equivalent to `team->people = p`) is valid but dangerous because that address will be invalid as soon as the function is finished.

Better create `p` with `malloc(sizeof (Person *) * MAX_PEOPLE)` instead of using the stack.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
Person *p[MAX_PEOPLE];
```

This allocates a local variable in the function to hold the array of people pointers.

You get the address of this local variable and send it back.  As soon as you are not in the function the local data is freed.  It was just allocated locally.  It is no longer valid.  I might work for a while or it might not depending on the the program does next.

You want this:

```
Person **p = (Person **)malloc(sizeof (Person *) * MAX_PEOPLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting the thing with pointer and memory management in C a little bit wrong. Consider reading a little bit more about it, before you continue coding your application.

Beside, I think you do not need an array of pointers to persons, but an array of persons.
Your struct is correct, but I would implement your function like that:

```
void addPeople(Team * team){
    team->numPeople = MAX_PEOPLE;
    team->people = malloc(sizeof(Person) * MAX_PEOPLE);
}
```

And do not forget to `free()` your `team->people`.

But if MAX_PEOPLE is an pre processor define, then it is totally unnecessary to use memory from the heap. If you are not storing too many people in your struct, the stack can easily fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Suppose if I allocate the full extent of `people` memory, how can I access then second, third, person in my `people`'s memory when it's not an array.

Comment: You can use the [] operator on a `Person *people;` variable. Just make sure, that the pointer points to a big enough space of memory, and that you do not access memory outside of its borders.